# Is there a geometric meaning of Stieltjes transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question

The wikipedia link is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation

Fourier transform gives the frequencies;  like Fourier Transform does Stieltjes transformation have a geometric meaning? In the wikipedia link there is nothing much about geometric views.